# How do I check in Django when on a subdomain or the main domain

Tags: python, django

How do I create an if statement in settings.py like the example below to check if the site is on a subdomain or main domain.

```
if main_domain == request.get_host():
    HOST_THEMES = [(main_domain, 'maindomain_theme'),
if subdomain == request.get_host():
    HOST_THEMES = [(subdomain, 'subdomain_theme'),
```

At the moment there is only options to set the subdomains explicitly and it's not going to work when running multiple subdomains. There must be a better way to do this.

Comment: Why not using regex to check if It's on subdomain or maindomain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in settings.py, you can use [socket.gethostname()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.gethostname)

```
import socket

if 'subdomain' in socket.gethostname():
    # set your subdomain
else:
    # set your maindomain
```

another version:

```
if socket.gethostname().split('.')[0] in ['subdomain1', 'subdomain2', ..]:
    # set socket.gethostname().split('.')[0] as subdomain
```

Comment: Nice. Is it possible to set _all_ subdomains in the if statement like a wildcard (*)?